# SQL Server staging table data type

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, etl, staging-table

I want to know what data type I should define in a staging SQL Server table when I don't know the exact data type of the source (csv files).

What are the best practices for optimizing resource?

Example:

- For text column: `varchar(255)` or `nvarchar(255)`?
- For date column: `date` or `datetime`?
- For decimal column: `decimal` or `float`? And what is the best precision in case of decimal?

Comment: Personal choice/opinion and depends on the file. Usually for loading a CSV file into a staging table I'd define everything as (n)varchar and cast as appropriate when processing the data.

Comment: Since the CSV source is already text (possibly containing extended characters) and for the actual text fields you do not know the max length in advance, then I believe safest would be `nvarchar(max)`. From there you can examine the content, select appropriate target types, validate using try_convert, and possibly flag certain records as rejects if they contain non-conforming data.

Comment: @Stu using nvarchar for all columns highly affect the data staging performance. Implicit conversion has a significant impact. You can refer to the following article for more information: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7475/ssis-performance-tuning-design-etl-pipelines/

Comment: @TN please check my comment above for the same reason.

Comment: @Hadi Until you know for sure that the data _doesn't_ contain Unicode, avoiding Unicode for performance reasons isn't wise - data loss / corruption is a far more serious issue than staging table performance.

Comment: @Hadi - I agree with the best practice of avoiding the use of character data types for storing values that are better represented as numerics, date/times, or other more appropriate types. However, the original post above started with the condition "when I don't know the exact data type of the source".

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree with that. This is why I said in my answer that there is no general solution; choosing the data types depends on several factors.

Comment: @TN I believe the question needs to be more specific and it is too broad. This is why I didn't agree with using nvarchar. The OP didn't clarify if the data types are of the same genre (text, numeric, binary) or not, besides some other essential factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is no general solution to your question. It depends on what data sources you are stagging. I will provide some questions and answers to help you choose the relevant data types.

> Can the same column have different genres of data types (text, numeric, binary)?

If yes, then in the staging table, you should use the data type that supports implicit conversion from other types. You can refer to the [following documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) to learn more about implicit conversion and SQL data types.

If No, you should use the data type that supports implicit conversion from the others. For instance, if the data source may be of `date` or `datetime` types, if the values contain time value, then you should use the `DateTime` type as it supports storing both types.

> Am I working with clean data?

If the data is clean, you should choose a data type similar to the destination database. For instance, if the source column may have an `integer` or `nvarchar` data type. At the same time, it always contains an `integer` value, and no erroneous data exists. Then it would be best if you used an `integer` data type in the staging table since it decreases the data buffer size.

> What do I need in the data destination?

This is the most critical question, as the data consumption should lead you to the relevant data type.

---

Finally, there may be other questions you should ask yourself before deciding. Be aware that using `nvarchar` for all columns may look like the safest method, but it highly affects the data staging performance. Implicit conversion has a significant impact. You can refer to the following article for more information:

- [SSIS Bad Habits: Decreasing SSIS Package Performance](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7475/ssis-performance-tuning-design-etl-pipelines/?utm_source=HadiFadlallah)

**Understanding the task requirements should be your first step in making that decision.**

Comment: As of SQL Server 2008, you should use `DATETIME2(n)` instead of `DATETIME`. It uses a less memory to be stored, and has greater date range (can handle dates to year 0), and you can define how many sub-second fractional digits you need